# Checking Firebase database for a key without downloading parent node?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime database that's structured like this:

```
referrals
 Test1: 0
 Test2: 0
```

I'm trying to check if "referral_code" exists in the database, this is the code I'm using:

```
exports.validateReferral = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const referral_code = data.ref
    console.log("Cloud verifying referral code, code is " + referral_code)
    admin.database().ref().child("referrals").once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.hasChild(referral_code)) {
            console.log("referral code is valid");
            return true
        } else {
            console.log("referral code is not valid");
            return false
        }
    })
})
```

When I run it, it shows "Cloud verifying referral code, code is Test1" but it also returns not valid despite the key being in the database.

Any idea how I can debug this? I tried logging the value of "snapshot" but none of the contents of Firebase snapshots show the actual values. Can anyone help me figure out how to locate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` at the top level of your code:

```
// 
return admin.database().ref().child("referrals").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.hasChild(referral_code)) {
        console.log("referral code is valid");
        return true
    } else {
        console.log("referral code is not valid");
        return false
    }
})
```

Without the top-level return, the return value from the asynchronous callback never reaches your client, and (worse) the code probably gets terminated before the result is ever read from the database.

---

But I recommend also changing the code to not download the entire `referrals` node just to check if one key exists. This accomplish the same and only downloads (at most) a single child node:

```
//                                                 
return admin.database().ref().child("referrals").child(referral_code).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    //    
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log("referral code is valid");
        return true
    } else {
        console.log("referral code is not valid");
        return false
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. But do you have any idea why I would be getting "Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" now?

Comment: Mixing the Promise and Callback API here won't return the boolean back to the caller.

Comment: Good catch Sam.     I had overlooked that this used classic callbacks. I fixed that now, but let me know if I missed something else. @TheNomadicAspie You might want to try again, although I'm not sure if the stack overflow was caused by the mixed promise/callback handling.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen restarting my computer before redeploying the functions and restarting the emulators somehow fixed the stack overflow, the only problem I'm having now is that despite "Test1" being a key in my Firebase database, and despite the code showing "Test1" in the console statement, it always returns false.

Comment: functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-validateReferral"
>  {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
>  Cloud verifying referral code, code is Test1
>  referral code is not valid
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-validateReferral" in ~1s

Comment: referrals:
     Test1: 0
     Test2: 0

Comment: Please don't provide extensive debug information in comments, as it's quite unreadable. Instead, edit your original question to provide an update of both the change you made based on my answer, and the output it generates that is still problematic.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the problem I'm having now is different enough I should probably ask a new question at this point, marking correct. Thank you again.